# View state on dropdown control

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

> ```
>  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
>  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false"   
>              OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Submitting...'; " 
>              Text="Click Me…" /></div>
>  <asp:DropDownList ID = "dListFruits" runat ="server" EnableViewState ="true"></asp:DropDownList>
>
> protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();
>     aList.Add("Apples");
>     aList.Add("Oranges");
>     if (!Page.IsPostBack)
>     {
>         dListFruits.DataSource = aList;
>         dListFruits.DataBind();
>
>         TextBox1.Text = "Hi";
>     }
> }
> protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>
> }
> ```

When i had a break point in a button click event , this peice of statement "dListFruits.DataSource" shows null while debugging. I thought view state will be applied before load event triggered. But when i see the page items are appended into the dropdown list. So view state will be applied just before render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check out the Items collection of the dropdownlist. Viewstate stores the items collection of dropdownlist control.